# What are the alternatives to RecyclerView for a feed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-mediaplayer, feed, litho

An app includes a feed like Twitter or Instagram. 
Tried it with the RecyclerView.
Would Litho (fblitho.com) be a good alternative to make a good feed with text, videos and pictures? Or maby other libraries?

Comment: Recommendations for frameworks and libraries are off topic for SO, see the [help].

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest learning more about `RecyclerView` before trying to move onto different libraries. Even if you do end up using another library, it's always good to have a better understanding of what it's being built on top of.

`RecyclerView` is the best way to handle feeds like you're looking to build. Even with images, or videos.

If you have any specific questions about `RecyclerView`, you should ask them here. For example, why does `RecyclerView` not fit your current needs?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to take a look at [epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy). As it description says, it is an Android library for building complex screens in a RecyclerView. Models are automatically generated from custom views or databinding layouts via annotation processing.

Wish it can help you.